# Removing spaces from MMAP in C

Tags: c, file-io, mmap

I'm trying to remove white spaces contained in a file and after I've read it using mmap, I proceed by removing white spaces by using a for-loop and shirting the next pointer to the current index but it doesnt seem to work. Here's my code to illustrate:

```
static unsigned long get_size_by_fd(int fd) {
    struct stat statbuf;
    if(fstat(fd, &statbuf) < 0) exit(-1);
    return statbuf.st_size;
}

fd = open("/home/text.txt", O_RDONLY);
file_size = get_size_by_fd(fd);
fb = mmap(0, file_size, PROT_READ || PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);

for (i = 0; i<file_size; i++) {
    if (fb[i] == 0x20) {
        fb[i] = fb[i++];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why the `0x20` instead of just `' '`?

Comment: @larsmans: I had the same thought, but given that we're dealing with a *file*, we should scan for a definite value in the file's assumed encoding, *not* in the language's execution cs.

Comment: @KerrekSB: hmm, I guess you're right.

Comment: @KerrekSB: That's a nice thought, but if there's `mmap` it's POSIX, and if it's POSIX, then it's compatible with ASCII.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no sequence point in the assignment `fb[i] = fb[i++];` so you get unspecified results. Better to write it plainly:

```
if (fb[i] == 0x20 && i + 1 < file_size))
{
    fb[i] = fb[i + 1];
    ++i;
}
```

I also added an additional bounds check (consider when there are spaces at the end).

Note that your program makes assumptions on the file encoding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all spaces, you must use two indexes:

```
for (i = 0, j = 0; i<file_size; i++) {
    if (fb[i] != 0x20) {
        fb[j++] = fb[i];
    }
}
```

After the loop has terminated, `j` tells you the new size which you must somehow enforce (probably with `truncate()` on the file).

Comment: this will remove all **non**-spaces.

Answer (score 0):

You should also open the file descriptor for reading and writing!